# Issue with a Process Object of Java

Tags: java, netbeans, process, outputstream, linphone

I have a problem with a Process Object of Java.

I want to open the process called linphonec.exe to make calls, and inside this process I have to insert a few command lines to do calls, answer ...

The problem comes when I have to insert more than one command line because the OutputStream of Process only accepts a command line when I call the close() method of OutputStream. If I dont call this method the command line isn't executed.

I want to execute more than one command but I can't.

Example:

"Call phone" and then "terminate" to end the call whenever I want.

But I can only insert the first command line and if I dont use the close() method the command line is not executed.

Code:

Start a process:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(PROCESS);
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process p = builder.start();
```

Read the InputStream of Process:

```
InputStream i = p.getInputStream();
System.out.print((char)i.read());
while(i.available() > 0){
    System.out.print((char)i.read());
}
```

Insert command line into OutputStream:

```
String command = com.nextLine();
OutputStream o = p.getOutputStream();
o.write(comando.getBytes());
o.flush();
o.close();
```

If I delete "o.close()" the command line is not executed, but if I execute it I can't execute the other command lines.

I tried the code on my program, but when I insert the command line I dont see the next information of the process.

When I put your code :

```
Ready
Warning: video is disabled in linphonec, use -V or -C or -D to enable.
linphonec> Registration on sip:XX.XX.XX.XX successful.
linphonec> call XXX
```

Exemple with my code:

```
Ready
Warning: video is disabled in linphonec, use -V or -C or -D to enable.
linphonec> Registration on sip:XX.XX.XX.XX successful.
linphonec> call XXX
Establishing call id to sip:XXX@XX.XX.XX.XX, assigned id 1
With "Available > 0" I get "Establishing call id to sip:XXX@XX.XX.XX.XX, assigned id 1".
```

If I use this loop I dont see the other info of the process.

I think the problem is that the outputstream does not get the command lines until I execute the Close method.

Thank you.

Sorry for my bad englando.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the problem is here:

```
    InputStream i = p.getInputStream();
    System.out.print((char)i.read());
    while(i.available() > 0){
        System.out.print((char)i.read());
    }
```

If there is a temporary pause in the stream of bytes coming from the process via the input stream, then `available()` will return zero and the read loop will terminate.  Game over.

Don't use `available()` ...

Here's what the loop *should* look like:

```
    InputStream i = p.getInputStream();
    int input;
    while ((input = i.read()) != -1) {
        System.out.print((char) input);
    }
```

Why does that work?

Instead of testing to see if there are bytes to be read, we just read anyway.  The `read()` call will block until either there is a character to read, or the "other end" closes the pipe.  In the latter case, `read()` will return a `-1` to indicate that the end-of-stream has been reached.

**UPDATE**

So that's not the problem.  (Or at least, not the whole problem).

Another possibility is that you are not writing the correct kind of line terminators to the output stream.  That could cause the external process not to get a "complete" command until you close the stream.

A third possibility is that you need to synchronize with the application; i.e. *wait* for the output from the first command before sending the second one, and so on.

Comment: I tried the code on my program, but when I insert the command line I dont see the next information of the process.

When I put your code :

Ready
Warning: video is disabled in linphonec, use -V or -C or -D to enable.
linphonec> Registration on sip:XX.XX.XX.XX successful.
linphonec> call XXX

Comment: Exemple with my code:

Ready
Warning: video is disabled in linphonec, use -V or -C or -D to enable.
linphonec> Registration on sip:XX.XX.XX.XX successful.
linphonec> call XXX
Establishing call id to sip:XXX@XX.XX.XX.XX, assigned id 1
With "Available > 0" I get "Establishing call id to sip:XXX@XX.XX.XX.XX, assigned id 1".

If I use this loop I dont see the other info of the process.

I think the problem is that the outputstream does not get the command lines until I execute the Close method.

Thank you.